# Почему последняя строчка "p = Console.ReadLine();" переноситься? Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, for

у меня есть прога

```js
var div = document.getElementById("hh");

function op(){
  var reg = /read\((.+?)\)/;
  var ab = div.innerHTML.replace(reg, '$1')
  var cc = ab.split(',')
  for(let i = 0; i < cc.length; i++){
     console.log(cc[i] + " = Console.ReadLine();");
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <h1> Hello, Dcoder </h1> 
  <div id="hh">
    read(a, b, к, р) 
  </div> 
  <button onclick="op()">click</button> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Результат:

[image: result]

**Вопрос:**
Почему последняя строчка "p = Console.ReadLine();" переноситься? Как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что там перенос строки стоит. Исправить: либо делать inline html, либо парсить на наличие конца строки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не умею парсить, а сделать inline html не вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы заменяете только участок строки посередине содержимого тега, а пробелы и переводы строки остаются по обоим бокам этого фрагмента и потом при разбиении строки по запятым прибавляются к первому и последнему элементу. Вам нужно или изменить регулярку так, чтобы она удаляла всё до и после оставляемого фрагмента, или извлекать только фрагмент в скобках (и лучше разбивать по запятым с пробелами, чтобы потом пробелы не добавляли отступы).

Оба варианта:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("hh");

function op(){
  var reg = /.+read\((.+?)\).+/s;
  var ab = div.innerHTML.replace(reg, '$1')
  var cc = ab.split(', ')
  for(let i = 0; i < cc.length; i++){
     console.log(cc[i] + " = Console.ReadLine();");
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <h1> Hello, Dcoder </h1> 
  <div id="hh">
    read(a, b, к, р) 
  </div> 
  <button onclick="op()">click</button> 
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
var div = document.getElementById("hh");

function op(){
  var reg = /read\((.+?)\)/;
  var ab = div.innerHTML.match(reg, '$1')[1];
  var cc = ab.split(', ')
  for(let i = 0; i < cc.length; i++){
     console.log(cc[i] + " = Console.ReadLine();");
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <h1> Hello, Dcoder </h1> 
  <div id="hh">
    read(a, b, к, р) 
  </div> 
  <button onclick="op()">click</button> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: у меня есть новая проблема...
вот у меня есть:

Текст
Текст
Текст
read(a, b)
Текст
Текст

И после split() оно получается так что cc[0] это:
Текст
Текст
Текст
a,

А cc[1] это:
b
Текст
Текст

И получается что = Console.ReadLine() пишется в самом конце

Comment: С новой проблемой и правда лучше задавать новый вопрос: у вас будет больше возможностей оформить вопрос более ясно, и ответов вы получите больше.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ab = div.innerHTML.trim().replace(reg, '$1')
                      ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: у меня есть новая проблема...
вот у меня есть:

Текст
Текст
Текст
read(a, b)
Текст
Текст

И после split() оно получается так что cc[0] это:
Текст
Текст
Текст
a,

А cc[1] это:
b
Текст
Текст

И получается что = Console.ReadLine() пишется в самом конце

Comment: @MaMkADoMa "новая проблема" - новый вопрос. У ответа - слева знак "галочка".