# Проблемки со .split()

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения, split

У меня есть проблемка:

вот моя программа:

```js
function TranslateIt() {
  firstTextarea = document.getElementById("1text_area");
  secndTextarea = document.getElementById("2text_area");

  secndTextarea.innerHTML =
    `<li>Hello guys</li>
  ` +
    firstTextarea.innerHTML.mreplace(/readln\((.+?)\)/gi, " = Console.ReadLine()")
}


String.prototype.mreplace = function(reg, res) {
  var done;
  firstStep = this.replace(reg, '$1')
  secondStep = firstStep.split(',')
  if (this.match(reg)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < secondStep.length; i++) {
      done += secondStep[i] + res + "</li><li>";
    }
    return done
  }
  return this;
};
```

```css
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TranslateIt()">Click</button>
<div>
  <code>
        <ol
          id="1text_area"
          contenteditable
        ><li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>readln(a, b);</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        </ol>
      </code> Result:
  <code>
        <ol
          id="2text_area"
          contenteditable
        ></ol
      ></code>
</div>
```

**Вопросы:** **1)** у меня получается так, что после `.split()` - `secondStep[0]` это:

Текст

Текст

Текст

a,

А `secondStep[1]` это:

b

Текст

Текст

И " = Console.ReadLine()" для аргумента "b"  пишется в самом конце

**2)** почему там в Результате, сверху, под "Hello guys" пишет `undefined`

Помогите пожалуйста всё это исправить :(

Мой прошлый вопрос на stackoverflow: [Почему последняя строчка "p = Console.ReadLine();" переноситься? Как это исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1233616/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-p-console-readline-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8)

Какой результат я хочу получить в итоге:

[image: result i need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про `undefined` вам уже объяснили: если вы не присвоите значение переменной, а потом прибавите к ней строку, то `undefined`, как начальное «значение» переменной, будет преобразовано в строку и попадёт в её начало.

Что касается второй проблемы, вам нужно захватить только содержимое скобок и делить только его. Для вашего случая хорошо подойдёт использование [`replace()` с функцией замены](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). Например, так:

```js
function TranslateIt() {
  firstTextarea = document.getElementById("1text_area");
  secndTextarea = document.getElementById("2text_area");

  secndTextarea.innerHTML =
    `<li>Hello guys</li>
  ` +
    firstTextarea.innerHTML.mreplace(/<li>readln\((.+?)\);<\/li>/gi, " = Console.ReadLine()");
}


String.prototype.mreplace = function(reg, res) {
  if (this.match(reg)) {
    return this.replace(
      reg,
      (fullMatch, subgroup) => {
        return subgroup
                .split(', ')
                .map(letter => `<li>${letter}${res}</li>`)
                .join('');
      }
    );
  }
  return this;
};
```

```css
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TranslateIt()">Click</button>
<div>
  <code>
        <ol
          id="1text_area"
          contenteditable
        ><li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>readln(a, b);</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        </ol>
      </code> Result:
  <code>
        <ol
          id="2text_area"
          contenteditable
        ></ol
      ></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

С undefined ответ простой.
Проинициализируйте

```
 var done = "";
```

Сложнее это с запятыми.
У вас всего одна запятая и вы по ней делите строку. Вот у вас и получается a, b где b это начало второго кусочка и ваш текст для замены добавляется в конец и первого и второго. Вот и все. Извините что не написал решения пишу с телефона того что вы хотите. Но если не помогут то постараюсь ответить завтра.

```js
function TranslateIt() {
  firstTextarea = document.getElementById("1text_area");
  secndTextarea = document.getElementById("2text_area");

  secndTextarea.innerHTML =
    `<li>Hello guys</li>
  ` +
    firstTextarea.innerHTML.mreplace(/readln\((.+?)\);/gi, " = Console.ReadLine()")
}


String.prototype.mreplace = function(reg, res) {
  var done = "";
  firstStep = this.replace(reg, '$1');
  
  secondStep = firstStep.split(',');
  if (this.match(reg)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < secondStep.length; i++) {
      done += secondStep[i] + res + "</li><li>";
    }
    return done
  }
  return this;
};
```

```css
ol {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TranslateIt()">Click</button>
<div>
  <code>
        <ol
          id="1text_area"
          contenteditable
        ><li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>readln(a, b);</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        <li>Текст</li>
        </ol>
      </code> Result:
  <code>
        <ol
          id="2text_area"
          contenteditable
        ></ol
      ></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо